# Ball not showing as a sphere in 3D plot

Tags: graphics3d

I an trying to mark a point with `Ball[]` on a `Plot3D` Surface.

```
Block[{soln},
 soln = Maximize[{x y^2 + y x^2, x^2 + y^2 <= 2}, {x, y}];
 Show[{Plot3D[{x y^2 + y x^2, x^2 + y^2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}],
    Graphics3D@Ball[Append[Values@soln[[2]], soln[[1]]], 5]}]
 ]
```

What I see is this. I don't see the Ball in 3D, rather it looks like a 2d projection.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at a vertical range in comparison to x/y. `Scale[Ball[..., 1], {1, 1, 30}]`

Comment: Thanks That Worked

Answer (score 2):

The [`Ball`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ball.html) has a radius of `5` which relative to the scale of the `z-axis` is flat. Instead of `Ball` use [`Ellipsoid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html) and set the z-radius to give you the desired appearance. Use [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to see the effect of varying the `z-radius`.

```
Manipulate[
 Block[{soln},
  soln = Maximize[{x y^2 + y x^2, x^2 + y^2 <= 2}, {x, y}];
  Show[{
    Plot3D[{x y^2 + y x^2, x^2 + y^2},
     {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
     ClippingStyle -> None],
    Graphics3D@
     Ellipsoid[
      Append[Values@soln[[2]], soln[[1]]],
      {5, 5, zr}]}]],
 {{zr, 100}, 25, 200, 25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The z axis is in a ratio of 20/600 to the x and y axes. So you need to use an ellipsoid with semi-axes that reflect the ratio within an isometric plotting box (i.e, a cube). Like so.

```
Block[{soln},
  soln = Maximize[{x y^2 + y x^2, x^2 + y^2 <= 2}, {x, y}];
  Show[
    Plot3D[{x y^2 + y x^2, x^2 + y^2}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[.4]],
    Graphics3D @ Ellipsoid[Append[Values @ soln[[2]], soln[[1]]], 5 {1, 1, 600/20}],
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
    ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image: plot]